# FormArray, Form Control for unit testing in angular (jasmine)

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, angular-reactive-forms

I am still new in Angular and Jasmine for unit testing. If code in component.ts like this

```
formGroup: FormGroup;

regexObj = {
    numberRegex: '^\d+$',
    nameRegex: '^[a-zA-Z0-9-_. ]*$',
    vendorRegex: '^[a-zA-Z0-9-_. ]*$',
    longLatRegex: '^[0-9.-]*$',
    priceRegex: '^[0-9]*$'
};



 
setBillboardIdValidator(index: number) {
     this.getForms().controls[index].get('billboardId').setValidators([Validators.pattern(this.regexObj.nameRegex), Validators.required]);
}


getForms(): FormArray {
    return this.formGroup.get('forms') as FormArray;
}
```

in component.spec.ts I write like this:

```
In component.spec.ts, I create like this
  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(UploadFormComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    component.form = new FormGroup({
      billboardName: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
    });
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('setBillboardNameValidator', () => {
    const control = component.form.controls['billboardName'];
    component.setBillboardNameValidator(9)
    expect(control).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

When I running the the unit test, I got message can not read property **TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined**. Can you help me what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Can you add `this.formGroup` initialisation as well?

Comment: in component.spec.ts ? @deepakchethan

Comment: in the component.ts

Comment: I did @deepakchethan

Comment: I meant the value assigned to it